# Java Tutorial .isEmpty() Method

Tags: java

I have 3 Classes (Printer, PaperTray and Machine) and my Main Java class (HelloWorld).

I am expecting to see "Load more paper!" as the output when this "myPrinter.print(2)" is called yet the output shows "My Printer is On!" twice, as though there is paper in the tray. I should only see the output showing the printer as on twice if there is enough paper being passed into loadPaper(which has been commented out for the time being until I get the load paper working):

```
import printing.Printer;

public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Printer myPrinter = new Printer(true, "MY PRINTER");
    //myPrinter.loadPaper(3);
    myPrinter.print(2);
}
}
```

From my Printer class:

```
package printing;

public class Printer extends Machine
{
    private String modelNumber;
    private PaperTray paperTray = new PaperTray(); //printer now HAS paper tray

public Printer(boolean isOn, String modelNumber)
{
    super(isOn); //calls the constructor of the machine class - Super calls inherited parent
    this.modelNumber = modelNumber;
}

public void print(int copies) 
{
    String onStatus = "";
    if(isOn)
    {
        onStatus = " is On!";
    }
    else
    {
        onStatus = " is Off!";
    }

    String textToPrint = modelNumber + onStatus;

    while(copies > 0 && !paperTray.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println(textToPrint);
        copies--;
        paperTray.usePage();
    }

    if(paperTray.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("Load more paper!");
    }   
}

//for each 
public void printColours()
{
    String[] colours = new String[] {"Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow" };

    //for current colour "in" colours
    for(String currentColour : colours)
    {
        if("Green".equals(currentColour))
        {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(currentColour);
    }
}

public void print(String text) 
{
    System.out.println(text);
}

public String getModelNumber()
{
    return modelNumber;
}

public void loadPaper(int count) 
{
    paperTray.addPaper(count);
}
```

}

When ".isEmpty()" is called, the value of pages is -2 yet I believe ".isEmpty()" only works when the value is equal to 0 exactly? So this is where I am guessing my problem is. Yet the code I have is (99% certain) the same as the tutors example.

The PaperTray class is :

```
public class PaperTray {

int pages = 0;

public void addPaper(int count) 
{
    pages += count;
}

public void usePage()
{
    pages--;
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return pages > 0;
}
}
```

Machine class:

```
public class Machine {

protected boolean isOn;

public Machine(boolean isOn)
{
    this.isOn = isOn;
}

public void TurnOn()
{
    isOn = true;
}

public void TurnOff()
{
    isOn = false;
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't your `PaperTray` start out with 0 pages, making it empty? You probably want to `addPaper` before your `print`.

Comment: Yeah I think it's supposed to until I pass an integer in the myPrinter.loadPaper().. which I seem to have left out of the main, will add that in, although I am expecting to still see "Load more paper", apologies if the question could have been worded better!

Comment: The `isEmpty` condition seems the wrong way round, and the code should prohibit there being -2 pages, IMO. (You shouldn't be able to use paper if the tray is empty...)

Comment: I see what you mean about the isEmpty condition, yet I have copied the tutorial exactly and it shows "return pages > 0;" which makes me think it is something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `isEmpty()` method is wrong in `PaperTray`, it now returns `true` if `pages > 0` (when it is full), and returns `false` if `pages <= 0` (when it is empty).

You need to switch the condition to `pages == 0` or to be absolutely sure `pages <= 0`.

Comment: Thanks skiwi but as I commented above the tutorial shows the isEmpty condition to be "return pages > 0;". I understand what you are saying about the condition but this makes me think some other logic in my code isn't working as it should?

Comment: I went with this to move on with the tutorial and it is working as expected, thanks!

Comment: @rjcarroll That must be an error in the tutorial then, without context is is hard to say though, but if they just gave that code without any notice that is was wrong, then yes an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your `isEmpty()` definition seems to be wrong

```
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return pages > 0; //shouldn't it be pages <=0 ?
}
```

Comment: There's no *need* for a constructor here. Constructing an empty tray and then calling `loadPages` is perfectly fine, especially for a tutorial API.

Comment: Thanks @chrylis, did not notice `addPaper(int count)` 
method